# Ruby undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, null

I'm a total beginner in ruby but I can't get out of this issue 
I get these when I run the code, it all works well until the end:

INPUT TEXT:  It all works well until

INPUT SUBTEXT:  ll

TEXT: It all works well until SUBTEXT: ll

OUTPUT:
4
15

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
(repl):18:in`initialize'

```
   puts "\nINPUT TEXT:"
    @text =  gets.chomp

puts "\nINPUT SUBTEXT:" 
    @subtext = gets.chomp

    puts "\nTEXT: " + @text
    puts "SUBTEXT: " + @subtext
    puts "\n"
    i = @text.index (@subtext)

    puts "OUTPUT:"

    while i != -1
            puts  i.to_s + ' '
            i = @text.index @subtext, i+1
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, `String#index` doesn't return -1 when the substring is not found; it returns `nil`.  Change your condition from `while i != -1` to `while i`. (This works because, unlike some other languages, Ruby considers the value 0 to be true; only `false` and `nil` are false.)

Answer (score 0):

Index return nil if substrings doesn't exist. So this should solve this issue

```
@text =  gets.chomp

puts "\nINPUT SUBTEXT:"
@subtext = gets.chomp

puts "\nTEXT: " + @text
puts "SUBTEXT: " + @subtext
puts "\n"
i = @text.index (@subtext)

puts "OUTPUT:"
while i
  puts  i.to_s + ' '
  i = @text.index @subtext, i+1
end
```